# How to specify additional fields returned by AQL in spec file?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I'm search Artifactory using AQL via a spec-file passed to the Jfrog CLI tool. If I were to post AQL directly to the REST API, I'm be able to use a normal, formal AQL statement and use `.include("some-field, e.g. stat")` to return specific fields. However, there doesn't appear to be a place for this in the spec-file format.

Artifactory's AQL documentation doesn't cover spec-files, and their spec-file documentation doesn't cover AQL.

I've grepped the spec-file parser module in the Go, and it seems to agree.

Has anyone had success, here?